# Working for two companies at the same time

Tags: contracts, company-policy, telecommute

Are there any concerns with working two remote full time tech jobs in the US (one in networking and one in photo sharing)? I understand there might be health concerns, but assuming you are able to complete tasks for both jobs each day and your work does not suffer for each, are their any other issues?

Comment: If both companies know about your other full-time employment and both companies are okay with it, what is the problem you have in the first place? If both companies don't know about the other employer, then it's likely you could be fired for lying to them. At any rate, the question as-is doesn't seem to actually be about an actual problem, and is asking a hypothetical that is unlikely to happen.

Comment: @jmac more than that you might get accused of corporate espionage and get sued big time

Comment: @ratchet, both companies would know about it, how exactly do you think this will become an issue? The companies may sue each other, but if they were going to do that, they wouldn't allow you to work for the other in the first place. This seems like such a contrived situation for oh-so-many reasons...

Comment: @jmac I meant in the case of them not knowing

Comment: @ratchet, in that case, isn't that the real issue here? The fact that you hid current employment from one of the employers? Or that you signed an agreement with two companies at the same time without indicating to them you were working for another company full time on the side?

Comment: @jmac I meant that depending on the pride of either/both employers and relative pettiness they would pull in corporate espionage charges and escalate the issue

Comment: they could be sub-contracting some of the work, 80hrs/week is hard to accomplish.

Comment: Q: In the UK, you can't be employed in two places without at least one place knowing it (because of your taxes). Is that possible in the USA?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> assuming you are able to complete tasks for both jobs each day and your work does not suffer for each, are their any other issues?

You **have** to check your employment contracts and terms of employment. Read everything you sign very, very carefully.

If you have non-compete or anything like that, you may be contractually unable to work for competitor.

Comment: Note this is true regardless of the number of hours you intend to work for either (especially when industries overlap)...

Comment: I can also guarantee that if you are assigned to work specific hours, they will fire you if you work for someone else during the same hours.

Comment: Also note that non-competes are almost entirely unenforceable in California

Answer (score 10):

Issues arise when there is a conflict of interest.

In your example, it ***appears*** the two careers are segregated. However, many people will take a second career between competing companies.

In this situation, it is best to be sure there is no conflict of interest or legal concerns.

In addition, both companies may feel (if they are aware of the situation) that you are not committed to them and subsequently get lower pay raises or passed for promotion.

Best to check with both companies to see if there are any conflicts.

> A conflict of interest (COI) occurs when an individual or organization
>   is involved in multiple interests, one of which could possibly corrupt
>   the motivation for an act in another.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict_of_interest

Answer (score 9):

> Are there any concerns with working two remote full time tech jobs in
>   the US (one in networking and one in photo sharing)? I understand
>   there might be health concerns, but assuming you are able to complete
>   tasks for both jobs each day and your work does not suffer for each,
>   are their any other issues?

The one word in your question that raises a red flag for me is "remote".

Are you planning to work 80 hours per week and thus work these jobs back-to-back? Or are you planning to work at these jobs simultaneously, and end up with something more like a 40-hour week?

If the former, and you truly meet the complete needs of both companies, it should probably be fine. People who work in an office often hold a side job (although not usually a full-time side job).

But if you were planning to interweave both jobs and execute them simultaneously, I'd be very concerned.

When I permit someone to work remotely, I'm expecting their full attention - just as I would if they were physically located in the office. Remote work isn't an opening for making extra money with your left hand while doing the work I assigned to you with your right - just as it isn't an opening for taking care of the children all day and only occasionally paying attention to your work.

If you have told both companies how you plan to work these two jobs (whatever that plan might be), and they have both agreed - then you should be fine. As long as everyone agrees, then anything could work.

But if you are reluctant to be completely honest with these two companies, then that says something about what you believe in your heart about your plan.

I always recommend honesty. My advice is to ask both of your employers if this is permissible, and follow their directions.

Comment: While you make a good point about the *extra* dangers of one remote job, I don't know if I agree with the general gist of "it's fine if it's two office jobs". Being physically present doesn't *really* mean anything, other than occupying some time and place with your body. Do you really think you have someone's "full attention" on their job in the forty hours they're at your company if they're also working a whopping forty hours somewhere else?

Answer (score 8):

Basically every company will have its own policies and the policy related to your question is called "Concurrent Employment"...Most of the companies mention in its "Concurrent Employment" policy that 
"An employee of our company shall not, without the prior approval of the managing director of the company, accept employment or a position of responsibility (such as a consultant or a director) with any other company, nor provide “freelance” services to anyone".

So be Careful.

Answer (score 7):

Generally full time employers assume that they are your primary work related commitment.  It varies from employer to employer how demanding that expectation is, but in most positions offering full time employment (particularly with benefits), it will not go well with your boss if you regularly have to reschedule your time at work due to other work-related engagements.  It's usually assumed that some level of interruption for family or health needs will come up, but it's not typical for a full time employee to be granted time off for the sake of working a second job.

I have trouble understanding a case where you could juggle the competing scheduling demands.  Obviously if the two schedules are locked in stone so that you know exactly how many hours and what times/days you'll be working, you could pull off two jobs, because they'd never compete.  But I have yet to see such an arrangement remain static and predictable in the long term.

I'd also expect very little advancement in either career at that point - it's hard to advance if you can't put in that little bit of extra work that lets you improve your skills.  With two jobs demanding full time hours, I'm not sure there'd be any slack for that.

I've seen people work a full time and a part time job - it's hectic, but doable if you have a clear set of priorities and way of arranging it.

Answer (score 0):

Each company would expect you to work 40 hours for them, in a well-awake and rested state, as any other employee would do. You are not going to do that. You may imagine that you would do it, but you won't. Even if you did, your employers won't believe it, just like I wouldn't believe it. Once they find out, the number of full time jobs will very quickly go from 2 to 0.